# java android jnetpcap eclipse install not working

Tags: java, android, jnetpcap

I have downloaded the latest version of jnetpcap and added it to my android project in eclipse as "Add external JAR". But when I'm running the program the application crashes immediately on my emulator and I receive the following error in the log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jnetpcap.Pcap
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile jnetpcap c files as shared library (.so) with the Android NDK first. Then you need to create your own JNI or use an existing one like [this](http://jnetpcap.com/userguide/android) made available in the official website related to this [thread](http://jnetpcap.com/node/760). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557955/1449056).

Answer (score 0):

Did you export the library?  In the Build Path of eclipse on the 4th page, make sure that it exists above any code that may use it, and make sure it's checked.