# android use pcap library

Tags: java, android, libpcap

I have a general question according an android app, I need to use some pcap functionality in my android app. Because java does not give the possibility in raw packet injections and low layer programming (as far as I know, pls correct me if I'm wrong) so I was looking for an alternative. So far I found the following:

- ANDROID NDK
- JNETPCAP

Any suggestions which one I should use or does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried on non-rooted phone? I need network sniffing functionality on non-rooted android phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The JNI Solution**

You need to *wrap* the calls and the logic you need out of libpcap in C or C++ and *expose* the underlying functions through [`JNI` *(Java Native Interface)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)  so your application can call native code in Java.

The documentation on `JNI` is pretty complete on internet, a lot of tutorials exists on this subject such as [this one](http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/04/tutorial-android-jni/).

If you want to easily wrap native code in JNI you can use `Swig` which allow you to automatically generate JNI code based on your C/C++ native headers.

The obtained JNI code should be compiled using the Android NDK as a *dynamic library* (.so). This library is to be placed in your application package under `libs/`. You can then invoke  `System.loadLibrary(path_to_you_dynamic_library)` to load all the symbols contained in the library and use them in Java.

**Using a third-party library**

If you're afraid of getting headaches while figuring out how to use JNI, you can look at this library which does the hard work for you, and provides an API to manipulate raw sockets in Java.

http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/

Answer (score 3):

> You need to wrap the calls and the logic you need out of libpcap in C or C++ and expose the underlying functions through JNI (Java Native Interface) so your application can call native code in Java.

Or you need to get a library that's already done that, such as, err, umm, [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com).

One problem you may have with *any* attempt to do packet capture on Android - or any *other* OS using the Linux kernel - is that, by default, the underlying kernel mechanism used by libpcap (`PF_PACKET` sockets) requires root privileges.  If there's a way to run your code as root, or to give it `CAP_NET_RAW` and possibly `CAP_NET_ADMIN` privileges, it might be possible to make it work.